# TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver -JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Getting Error while generating pdf using JSPDF - Error: TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver,

Below is the code and I am using version 2.4.0

```
const doc = new jsPDF.jsPDF({ unit: 'pt', putOnlyUsedFonts: true});
const pdfElement = document.getElementById('id');
var pdfName = 'Test.pdf';
doc.html(pdfElement, {
    callback: (pdf) => {
      pdf.save(pdfName)
    },
    margin: 20,
});
```

Environment - AngularJs and RequireJs

Comment: I don't get any errors in (this setting)[https://jsfiddle.net/9zw6qsgh/]. Please add more info - how do you import the libraries, what other functions you use, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am not getting the error in my local also, once I deployed this dev then getting the error. USing Angularjs and requireJs

Comment: `jsPDF.html` returns an object of type [`Worker`](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/dist/jspdf.es.js#L14939) which is an extension/hack around the standard `Promise` and the most likely candidate for producing the type of error you get. I'd start debugging by `console.log`-ging the result of the call to `doc.html` in a working environment vs. the non-working one.

Comment: I couldn't solve this issue but I changed my implementation to use html2pdf which is a wrapper for both the jsPDF and html2canvas,

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the exact issue with the latest (v2.5.1) version.

It turned out that it is not an issue with jspdf. Instead, it was the NewRelic agent causing the [issue](https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008e3OWAQ/having-promise-error-from-thirdparty-library-by-using-browser-agent-code).

If you are using the `Lit` New Relic browser agent type, change it to `Pro` agent type. To do so:

- Follows the step at: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/browser-monitoring/installation/install-browser-monitoring-agent/
- Update the snippet of code in the document Head

Comment: I can confirm that for my specific implementation, removing the New Relic agent snippet from my `index.html` did cause the error to go away, and allowed the PDF document to be generated. 

It's also important to note that this seems to be related to the `.html()` method, which I believe delegates some of the "heavy lifting" to `html2canvas`. Although, I also believe `dompurify` might be in the mix too, when providing a value of type `string`. I am providing a string to `.html()`, so I cannot be certain that the issue is _NOT_ with `dompurify`.